# PHPStorm CLI debugging on Vagrant instance

Tags: php, debugging, vagrant, phpstorm

I'm trying to get PHPStorm to work with Xdebug to use with PHP scripts (CLI, *not* web pages!) on a `vagrant` instance on the same machine as PHPStorm is running on.

In their [docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+CLI+scripts+with+PhpStorm) they say this:

> To tell the PhpStorm which path mapping configuration should be used
>   for a connection from certain machine, the value of the PHP_IDE_CONFIG
>   environment variable should be set to serverName=SomeName, where
>   SomeName is the name of the server configured in Settings /
>   Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers:
>
> Windows: set PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=SomeName"   Linux / Mac OS X:
>   export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=SomeName"

However, it's unclear where I'm supposed to set this-- is it set somewhere in the PHPStorm app? Is it set as part of the `bash` profile in the vagrant box? In the vagrant `xdebug` conf?

Comment: *"Is it set as part of the bash profile in the vagrant box?"* -- yes.

Comment: PhpStorm since v8 supports debugging CLI scripts over SSH directly (via Remote PHP Interpreters)-- there you do not need to do anything like that. But you may need to setup SFTP deployment and use that when creating Remote PHP Interpreter (it depends: in some cases IDE cannot use/interpret path mappings from vagrant config file): 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+Remote+PHP+Interpreters+in+PhpStorm

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPStorm + XDebug + Vagrant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724328/phpstorm-xdebug-vagrant)

Answer (score 0):

A per [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681474/phpstorm-cli-debugging-on-vagrant-instance#comment51304683_31681474) comment, PhpStorm since v8 supports debugging CLI scripts over SSH directly (via Remote PHP Interpreters)-- there you do not need to do anything like that. But you may need to setup SFTP deployment and use that when creating Remote PHP Interpreter (it depends: in some cases IDE cannot use/interpret path mappings from vagrant config file.

See:

- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel
- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+Remote+PHP+Interpreters+in+PhpStorm